# Address Validation API - Use in South Africa

Tags: google-address-validation-api

I tried using the demo first and then entered an address in Cape Town SA. Firstly the dropdown for choosing region does not cater for South Africa. The address would also not be validated when I select unknown as region. Kindly Assist

I tried using demo and was expecting address to be validated before we sign up.

Answer (score 0):

South Africa is not supported as per this [document](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/address-validation/coverage?_gl=1*gx64ap*_ga*MTkxODk2MTE4OS4xNjg3NTI1NzQ5*_ga_NRWSTWS78N*MTY4NzUyNTc0OC4xLjEuMTY4NzUyNjU3NS4wLjAuMA..)